# What's the difference between sterilize and disinfect?

Tags: difference

Whey they both mean make something clean or kill bacteria

Comment: Can you tell us the context in which these words were used? I ask because it might be important depending on what products the instructions appear.  These words mean pretty much the same, as you say. But according to this website https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/sterilization-and-disinfection, there is a difference on the scientific level, e.g. bacteria and microbes.

Answer (score 1):

Both words are used to refer to the process of making something cleaner.

However, if we delve deeper into the scientific community, sterilization has a higher emphasis on eliminating **all** microorganisms. Sterilization has a higher scrutiny to it. For example, I know research labs that would still sterilize brand new apparatus that just arrived. The typical way to sterilize apparatus is to **autoclave** them, which means to subject it to high heat and pressure for optimal sterilization.

Despite the apparatus arriving in a seemingly pristine condition, know that some experiments are highly sensitive to external variables such as the presence of microorganisms. And having worked as a lab assistant myself, we have never used the term "disinfect" when referring to cleaning something relatively clean, such as brand new equipment.

To put things simply, `sterilization` has a higher emphasis for complete removal of microorganisms and `disinfection` tends to be the better word when trying to make already contaminated surfaces clean.